# PHP - cURL file upload generates 415 http code

Tags: php, image, rest, curl, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image file to a RESTful API using POST, without an html form, and I'm having some issues.

```
$data_string = "@../upload_files/images/".$data.";type=image/png";

    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $http_headers = array(
        'Content-Type: image/png'
    );

    if (isset($_SESSION['Auth']))
        $http_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['Auth'];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

This is returning an HTTP code 415, and the content-type defined in $info is null, even though I defined it. Is there something I'm missing here, or is just not possible to POST an image to a server that wasn't uploaded via an html form?

Comment: You should specify full (absolute) path to uploading file. `../upload_files/images/` is a relative path.

Comment: Would that be 'http://localhost/etc/upload_files/images/' then?

Comment: Use [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to convert relative path to absolute path

Comment: I've tried this, but still no luck. Anything else it might be?